# Interior point of convex polytope

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Suppose the convex polytope is the set of feasible solutions $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for the linear system $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}\,,\; \mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ subject to some (linear) constraints $\mathbf{0}\leq\mathbf{x}\leq\mathbf{v}$; how is it possible to select an interior point of said polytope, i.e. it doesn't lie on an edge or vertex of the polytope?

Does the algorithm requires the knowledge of what the vertices of the polytope are?

Comment: Project the center of the domain onto the solution of the system.

Comment: If your polytope is given by $Ax \leq b$ you can use linear programming. But I don't understand the way you define your polytope.